# How to set the required field for md-autocomplete dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

trying to use `md-autocomplete` inside a custom directory.

I wanted the field to be required based on two conditions. One which is initialized(cond1) and one that changes(cond2)

I've tried to do it like this:
`required="{{ cond1 && !cond2 }}"`

But for some reason the `md-autocomplete` always becomes required, even if cond1 is initially `undefined` or `false`. It also doesn't respond to changes done to the value of `cond2`.

The validator also doesn't check if the selected-item has been set. It just checks if there is text in the field.

`ng-required` doesn't seem do anything.

Any ideas how i can make this work?

EDIT:

Here is my directive's .html

```
<div ng-form="dummyForm">
    <md-autocomplete
            md-input-name="{{ctrl.fieldName}}"
            md-selected-item="ctrl.dummyItem"
            md-selected-item-change="ctrl.setSelectedItem()"
            md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
            md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.display || item"
            md-min-length="0"
            placeholder="{{ ctrl.placeholder }}"
            ng-disabled="ctrl.selectAll || ctrl.isDisabled"
            required="{{ ctrl.isRequired && !ctrl.selectAll }}">
        <md-item-template>
            <span>{{ item.display || item }}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
            No results.
        </md-not-found>
    </md-autocomplete>
</div>
<div class="label-wrapper">
    <label
            class="checkbox-label"
            ng-if="ctrl.selectAll !== null">
        <input
                type="checkbox"
                ng-model="ctrl.selectAll"
                ng-change="ctrl.checkSelectAll()">
        {{ ctrl.checkboxName ? ctrl.checkboxName : 'Select all' }}
    </label>
</div>
```

It is basically just a custom input field that lets the user either select a value from the list OR click the checkbox to "select all" items. When the checkbox is selected, i don't want the `md-autocomplete` field to be required anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work fine with `ng-required` as you can see in this [demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/roMEMuOoB5ZkFM7rCvJ6?p=preview).

#### View

```
<form name="myForm">
    <md-autocomplete 
        md-autoselect=true
        placeholder="What is your favorite place?"
        md-item-text="item.display"
        md-items="item in ctrl.items"
        md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template"
        md-min-length="2"
        md-delay="ctrl.throttle"
        md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
        md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-select-on-match=true
        md-match-case-insensitive=true
        md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
        ng-required="ctrl.cond1 && !ctrl.cond2"
        md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem">

   {{ myForm.$error }}

   <div>
       <md-button type="submit">Submit</md-button>
   </div>
</form>
```

#### AngularJS controller

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    this.cond1 = true;
    this.cond2 = false;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Im using my md-autocomplete inside a custom directive though. I wrapped it in an ng-form div so the parent form applies its validation. But i just cant seem to be able to set the required attribute correctly.

Comment: @mTv this info is important. Please add your custom directive to your question.

Comment: Edited comment.

Comment: @mTv  `ng-required="ctrl.isRequired && !ctrl.selectAll"` should work for you.

Comment: Yes it does:/Must have removed some tinker code from earlier now then that made it work:D Thanks!

Comment: ng-required has a bug and dont remove required from input tag